# Show Bootstrap alert box on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following code shows an alert box:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Dismissal Alert Messages</h2>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            Success! message sent successfully.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I show alert box on button click?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This jsfiddle shows how you can show a bootstrap alert box on click

http://jsfiddle.net/g1rnnr8r/2/

You need to implement jquery's `show()` method. The code you need to use is.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.alert').show()
    }) 
});
```

Comment: when I used it second time it is not working :( it works only after page refresh

Comment: ah ok, let me fix that @Neo. can you confirm that every time you click the button you want a new alert box to appear

Comment: yes actually i will use it and generate alerts dynamically..on success and failure I will show a alert message.

Comment: @Neo hey, try this, it works as you asked (I hope) http://jsfiddle.net/uxzobhen/2/ changed it slightly again, I think this works best. let me know

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald clicking the button every times adds new message which is not idea. just add `$('.parent').empty();` before appending alert div to the parent fixes the issue.

Comment: it says that the alert is removed from dom

Answer (score 9):

```js
function showAlert(){
  if($("#myAlert").find("div#myAlert2").length==0){
    $("#myAlert").append("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable' id='myAlert2'> <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'  aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button> Success! message sent successfully.</div>");
  }
  $("#myAlert").css("display", "");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button value="showAlert" onclick="showAlert();"> Show Alert</button>

    <div class="container" style="display:none;" id="myAlert">
        <h2>Dismissal Alert Messages</h2>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" id="myAlert2">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            Success! message sent successfully.
        </div>

    </div>
```

**Edited**

I've added some IDs and written some code.
Try to understand, If you are not getting ask me.
Okay
Hope this will help for you, If not ask me for more.

Comment: when I clicked button second time it is not working :( it works only after page refresh

Comment: I've updated, check it now the alert will come, second time, third time ... all the time.Okay

Answer (score 4):

Try This.
What is done here is:

1. Added one button "Show Alert message".
2. By Default alert message will be hidden.
3. On click of "Show alert message" alert message will be shown

```js
$("#btnShow").click(function(){
  
  $(".alert").hide().show('medium');
});
```

```css
.alert{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      
        <h2>Dismissal Alert Messages</h2>
      
      <button id="btnShow">Show Alert message</button>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            Success! message sent successfully.
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: when I clicked button second time it is not working :( it works only after page refresh

Comment: nice, I like this solution @Puneet

Comment: After clicking close button the message is not shown again

Answer (score 4):

You can check this one:

```
 <div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
            <a  class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create custom modal dialog box, then you could use this small library for it: http://bootboxjs.com/

```
<!-- bootbox code -->
    <script src="bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
            bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
                console.log("Alert Callback");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Otherwise you need to create the modal and javascript triggers manually.

Comment: custom but using my above code , can you help me to modify it ?

Comment: nice one is it available with `alert` in bootstrap 4